# react-native loginwithpermissions promise not resolved on android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

After upgrading a react-native from 0.56 to 0.59.8 (using FBSDK 0.10.1), the facebook login don't work anymore on android.

when I fill the Fb login form and continue, LoginManager.logInWithPermissions promise does not resolve and never goes to .then() after logInWithPermissions()

here is my code:

```js
loginWithFBSDKLoginManager() {
    LoginManager.logOut();
    const self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(function (result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          return;
        }
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
          const accessToken = data.accessToken.toString();
          const userID = data.userID.toString();
          self
            .getUserInfos(accessToken)
            .then((response) => {
              resolve({ ...response, accessToken, userID });
            })
            .catch(
              function (error) {
                reject(error);
              }
            );
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

I tried to put breakpoint almost everywhere but nothing help.
To most strange thing is that work perfrectly on iOS, this issue only occurs on Android.

I tried to debug my app using Android Studio and the only error found in the console is

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to display
>   'https://m.facebook.com/intern/common/referer_frame.php' in a frame
>   because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.", source:
>   [https://m.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=2129868160675609&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A1562743341374%7D&sdk=android-5.0.3&scope=public_profile%2Cemail&state=%7B%220_auth_logger_id%22%3A%22edb48b96-de45-47e6-8331-f3db300e4eb2%22%2C%223_method%22%3A%22web_view%22%7D&default_audience=friends&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&auth_type=rerequest&display=touch&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&return_scopes=true&ret=login&fbapp_pres=0&logger_id=edb48b96-de45-47e6-8331-f3db300e4eb2#*=*](https://m.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=2129868160675609&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A1562743341374%7D&sdk=android-5.0.3&scope=public_profile%2Cemail&state=%7B%220_auth_logger_id%22%3A%22edb48b96-de45-47e6-8331-f3db300e4eb2%22%2C%223_method%22%3A%22web_view%22%7D&default_audience=friends&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&auth_type=rerequest&display=touch&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&return_scopes=true&ret=login&fbapp_pres=0&logger_id=edb48b96-de45-47e6-8331-f3db300e4eb2#_=_) (0) I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(53)] "ErrorUtils caught an error:
>   "Script error.". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see
>   https://fburl.com/debugjs.", source:
>   https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3iEpX4/ys/l/fr_FR/LDgA15LzuMu.js
>   (53) I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(262)] "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked
>   a frame with origin "https://m.facebook.com" from accessing a frame
>   with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of
>   "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols
>   must match.
>       ", source: https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3iEpX4/ys/l/fr_FR/LDgA15LzuMu.js
>   (262)

Could somebody help me solving this? or guide me to find the root cause.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I manageed to solve it by upgrading from `v0.10.1` to `v1.0.1`. Remember to remove all the `CallbackManager` stuff in `MainApplication.java`